# Unity GUI not showing after building

Tags: unity-game-engine

A couple of months ago I made the last working build. I made some irrelevant changes in the code and rebuild the code, only this time I find out my entire GUI is gone. I don't see any buttons any more.

Could this happen because of a Unity/Windows update? (I did upgrade Unity) 
the current version of my Unity is version 4.5.5

Comment: I think the *c#* tag is obsolete here, as this question is not specific or directly related to C#.

Comment: Must have been a mistake, removed.

Comment: If you haven't been able to rule out your own changes to your code as a possible cause, I would look into that first.